# "thrilled to her": thrill with indirect object

Tags: meaning, verbs

The New York Times ran a [story] (https://www.nytimes.com/2019/07/27/us/politics/kamala-harris-2020-election.html?action=click&module=Top%20Stories&pgtype=Homepage) today on Kamala Harris which included the following

> Democratic voters have thrilled to her as a messenger, yet the content of her message remains a work in progress.

I can more or less make sense of the sentence but this use of *thrill* is new to me. Is it standard? rare? an error? Perhaps it should be *thronged*? (My first reaction was to say *thralled* but I can find no support for that.)

[The Free Dictionary] (https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/thrill+to) affirms the usage

> **thrill to (something)**
>   To become greatly excited by or joyful from something.

The usage, then, is standard, but I don't believe I've ever heard it.

**Is this use of *thrill* regional? Or is the distinction femoral, and it is either falling into or out of favor?**

Or maybe I'm just ignorant.

Comment: It’s standard usage, possibly more BrE than AmE. You can think of it as “thrilled to (have/accept/etc) her as a messenger”: they were happy with her.

Comment: People thrill to a rallying cry, a tune, etc.

Comment: 'Thrill to' is a transitive multi-word verb (traditionally 'phrasal verb'); in 'Democratic voters have thrilled to her', _her_ is the object of the transitive verb _thrill to_, not the indirect object of the verb _thrill_. Compare 'Jill objected to the amendment'. A multi-word verb is a verb, even if it ends in 'for' or 'to'.